# docker volume couldn't find folder

Tags: node.js, database, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to make my database folder persist, but it fails.

error:

[image]

this is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.7"

services: 
    app:
        build: .
        volumes: 
            - ./.db-data:/usr/src/app/database/
```

dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

folder structure:

[image]

Comment: Check that the `WorkingDir` is set properly by `docker inspect` the docker image. If not, try setting the `working_dir` option in docker-compose.

Comment: @myeongkilkim the log output gave to me: ```"WorkingDir": "/usr/src/app",```

Comment: @myeongkilkim i also added ```working_dir``` as the same as Dockefile but it fails too 

Comment: The content of the part that uses the database module of app.js is required. Apart from this, the hierarchy looks a little weird. Currently .db-data is not visible in the folder, and .db-data is mounted as /usr/src/app/database by the volumes mounting of docker-compose, and it seems to crash. because already existing /usr/src/app/database is a `COPY . .` of the Dockerfile exists on the image.

Comment: In other words, Depending on what your intent is, you need to change the docker/docker-compose files.
Whether there is .db-data data on the host PC, whether there is data in the database folder, whether you want to keep the data in the database folder other than .db-data, etc.. I can't figure out what the intention is. could you tell me?

Comment: @myeongkilkim i want to keep the data in the database folder on .db-data folder on host.